# Cannot connect to OpenVPN within double NAT network

Tags: openvpn, nat, pfsense

I recently setup a PFSense router behind my existing DDWRT (with Wifi) router. I'm trying to learn the ropes of PFSense so this double NAT situation is necessary.

I setup an OpenVPN server on the PFSense box. It works well when connecting from outside the home network but I cannot connect while on DDWRT's WiFi network.

I am connecting via the DDWRT's public IP which forwards all traffic on 1194 to 192.168.1.145 (the PFSense WAN port). The PFSense LAN is 10.10.1.0/24 with OpenVPN on 10.10.2.0/24.

I'm not sure what logs or configurations to include. Please let me know if you need any information.

Comment: This will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: @DavidPostill After a bit of research, that does seem to be my issue. Unfortunately I haven't been able to fix it with the solutions I've found online. They all seem to be about a 4-5 year old bug with ddwrt.

Comment: and what happens when you are on WiFi and connect via PFsense WAN ip on the first segment? i.e 192.168.1.145 that should work